# WSO2 Admin Console - Add button under Manage->Services is disabled

Tags: wso2

I am trying to deploy a service as .aar service on WSO2 ESB Server through the option

Manage->Services->Add->AAR Service in WSO2 ESB Admin Console (localhost)

Th 'Add' button seems disabled. Why is this so??

PS: Using version 4.8.1

Comment: Which broswer version are u using. Please check the carbon logs to see if there is any error printed.